# is_super_admin() call produces fatal error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress network.I am trying to use is_super_admin() function in my plugin,but wordpress gives the error below:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /PathToWordpresDir/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1373
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wordpress plugin -> Call to undefined function wp\_get\_current\_user()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127559/wordpress-plugin-call-to-undefined-function-wp-get-current-user)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a bug in `WordPress`. To resolve, try the following within your plugin / theme:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../')."/wp-includes/pluggable.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

The better answer is to wrap whatever thing you're doing in a function, and hook it onto the plugins_loaded or init hook. (see the wp-settings.php file)

**Example:**

```
add_action('init','do_stuff');
function do_stuff(){
  if (is_super_admin()) {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127607/794071