# get_user_by() undefined in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I'm writing a plugin that parses a json feed and generates pages programatically from the feed.  I want to create a user programatically that will be the author of the pages. The problem is when I call `username_exists()` this function internally calls `get_user_by()` which ultimately is undefined.  My guess is there is some action I need to hook into or some other event that needs to be done first but I'm at a loss.  Here's the code, and the error apache is throwing back:

```
/**
 * A simple class for the cron user, ie the 'author' that will
 * generate pages from the feed
*/
class PP_CronUser {

  private static $cronUserName = 'Cron User';
  private static $cronEmail = 'asdf';
  private static $cronPW = 'asdf';
  private static $ID = null;

  public static function getUserID() {
    if(!is_null(self::$ID)) return self::$ID;
    if(!($id = username_exists(self::$cronUserName))) { //Here's the offending line
    self::$ID = $id;
    return $id;
    }   
    self::$ID = wp_create_user(self::$cronUserName, self::$cronPW, self::$cronEmail); 
    return self::$ID;
  }
}
```

The error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_user_by() in
>   `/home/who_cares/wordpress/wp-includes/user.php` on line 1198

So `username_exists` is defined but this calls `get_user_by` internally which is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a *duplicate*, but the problem is the same, and likely solved by, [wordpress plugin -> Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6127559/1432801)

Answer (score 8):

It means the WordPress core has not loaded when you try to call that function.

One solution is to hook it:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    $user_id = PP_CronUser::getUserID();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Thus you just have to call `wp-blog-header.php` in the top of your plugin file make sure you mention the correct path

```
require('path/to/wp-blog-header.php');
```

> Note this Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_user_by() error
>   occurs when you call any undefined function or there is no definition
>   of the function

Answer (score 1):

I was right in thinking I needed to hook to something.  I was calling this method directly from the plugin.  Attaching to the admin_menu hook allowed all the necessary libraries to load.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Patrick This particular post should not be an edit - it's a self-answer.

Comment: The most correct action is probably `'init'`, see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6127607/1432801)