# Getting 'Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()' error when do_action is used

Tags: php, wordpress

Note that this question was created to avoid `global $plugin_name;`

---

I am writing a WordPress (WP 3.6) plugin and I am getting

`wp_get_current_user() in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1281, referer: http://10.1.1.6/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mhomepage/mhomepage_admin_menu.php` if I use this code

```
$plugin_name='mhomepage';

// Hook for adding admin menus
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_plugin_admin_page', 10, 1);
do_action('admin_menu', $plugin_name.'/mhomepage_admin_menu.php');

// add_action('admin_menu', 'add_plugin_admin_page');

function add_plugin_admin_page($plugin_name) {
    // global $plugin_name;

    //must check that the user has the required capability 
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options'))
    {
      wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.') );
    }

    add_menu_page( 'mHomePage', 'mHomePage', 'manage_options', 'mhomepage/mhomepage_admin_menu.php', '', '', 6 );
    // add_menu_page( 'mHomePage', 'mHomePage', 'manage_options', $plugin_name, '', '', 6 );
}
```

where the `mhomepage_admin_menu.php` looks like

```
<?php

    echo "Plugin menu page";

?>
```

but in case I use `add_action('admin_menu', 'add_plugin_admin_page');`
in the above code instead of

```
// add_action('admin_menu', 'add_plugin_admin_page', 10, 1);
// do_action('admin_menu', $plugin_name.'/mhomepage_admin_menu.php');
```

everything works fine? Could someone explain what and why is  happening and what the solution would be? I want to use do_action to pass the argument to add_plugin_admin_page function.

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127607/250422 but I am not sure if it applies to my case too and I really don't understand what I would be supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead if you want to pass arguments to your function

```
// Hook for adding admin menus
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_plugin_admin_page', 10, 1);
do_action('admin_menu', $plugin_name);
```

The first line you're creating an action that you have told to hook into a WordPress function. The second line that action with the arguments.

[do_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action)

**EDIT**

Since it may or may not be wise to add arguments to default WordPress action hooks. Let's try and separate it in a different way.

Create your own hook

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_plugin_admin_page', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'plugin_admin_page', 'plugin_admin_page_arguments' );

function plugin_admin_page_arguments() {
  $plugin_name = 'Hello World'; // Your argument
  do_action('plugin_admin_page', $plugin_name);
}
```

Then your admin page function and it's argument

```
function add_plugin_admin_page($plugin_name) {
  echo $plugin_name;
}
```

This isn't tested but it should give you an idea

Comment: But in the link you provided is `add_action( 'i_am_hook', 'who_is_hook', 10, 2 );do_action( 'i_am_hook', $a, $b );` and the I followed in my code.

Comment: I have made an edit here. I did get the hook bit wrong sorry about that. It's been amended with a more comprehensive answer. It's not tested - but hopefully it should give you an idea. If you get any issues let me know.

Comment: OK, I think I got it ... just thinking how to declare the $plugin_name variable outside any function. On the same level as we call add_action().

Comment: global $plugin_name; :)

Comment: Yes ;-) That's what I wanted to avoid, that's why I created this question ;-)