# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I wanted to store the current user ID to the database, but instead I got that error, the php file is custom and i put it inside my wordpress theme folder, how can I fix this? I wanted to make a simple custom php script that can store data to the database. And I think wp_get_current_user() is the problem, how do I use it properly?

Here is my code

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$current_user_id = $current_user->ID;

$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['title']);
$department = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['department']);
$date_today = date("Y-m-d");
$doc = $_FILES['fileName']['name'];
$doc_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/documents/" . $doc;



$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_document (ID,
                              department, 
                              title, 
                              submit_date,
                              doc_path,
                              revision_count,
                              rejection_count,
                              status) 
        VALUES ($current_user_id, '$department', '$title','$date_today', '$doc_path', 0, 0, 'Not Reviewed')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: Check your includes

Comment: What do you mean? what should I check? I'm kinda new with wordpress

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wordpress plugin -> Call to undefined function wp\_get\_current\_user()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127559/wordpress-plugin-call-to-undefined-function-wp-get-current-user)

Comment: No, I still got an error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use WordPress functions or `WPQuery`

```
include('/var/www/html/pub_html/wp-blog-header.php');
$prefix =  $wpdb->base_prefix;
```

Include above file on your custom PHP it will establish WordPress connections

Comment: I just need to include wp-blog-header.php thanks for the help!! work like a charm!

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Not all WordPress located at the path you specified. Also, never use `include()`, use `require()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Recently Faced same error and fixed using below code

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) {
    include(ABS_PATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Warning: Use of undefined constant ABSPATH - assumed 'ABSPATH' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) still got an error

Comment: Spelling mistake, it should be `ABS_PATH`