# add_menu_page() not working on plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

Basically, I'm in the process of making a little plugin for my WordPress site, I'm encountering the most annoying problem I can find, My current structure is like such
**/wp-content/plugins/videos/videos.php**

The content inside the **PHP** file is as follows :

```
if(!class_exists('WP_GraceMedia_Videos')) {

    class WP_GraceMedia_Videos {

        public function __construct() {
            add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'add_menu_page'));
        }

        public function add_menu_page() {
            $page_title = "GraceMedia Video Management";
            $menu_title = "GraceMedia Videos";
            $capability = "edit_options";
            $menu_slug = "videos/videos-admin.php";
            $function = "";
            $icon_url = plugins_url('videos/images/icon.png');
            $position = "6";
            add_menu_page($page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position);
        }

        public static function deactivate() {

        }

        public static function activate() {

        }

    }

    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('WP_GraceMedia_Videos', 'activate'));
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('WP_GraceMedia_Videos', 'deactivate'));

}
```

It all appears to be correctly formatted to me, It's actually activating the plugin and letting me de-activate it, It's just not adding the item to the **WP Admin Menu**

Comment: The question is answered with the updated answer in the following reply.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24669032/1287548

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capability "edit_options" you have in your `add_menu_page` code does not exist according to the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). Try changing it to something like "edit_theme_options".

Answer (score 1):

use the 'manage_options' instead of 'edit_options'.