# I can't login on admin page after i update wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, admin

when i try to login ,displayed this: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_menu_page() in /home/u613978711/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/panel/mpane`

before showed, on plugins, but when i remove plugins from FTP, now show this on THeme, how can i fix, and how can i update wordpress without any problem

Comment: take a look into : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598971/wordpress-and-call-to-undefined-function-add-menu-page

Answer (score 0):

Update the Wordpress Version so Function.php file is changed
    so please create the hook

```
 <?php
     add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu');
     function my_menu()
     {
         add_menu_page('My Menu', 'My Test', 'manage_options', 'my-page-slug', 'my_function');
     }
     function my_function()
      {
           echo "Hello";
       }
       ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Maulik's Answer above is correct, Also you may try the following below:

Login from FTP and goto `wp-content/themes` and rename your theme with some other name. Once you are done, Open your home page, It'll force wordpress to apply the default theme. (Don't worry you can apply the theme again in `Appearance > Themes`). And try logging in again. It should work now.

If successful, Try applying the theme again.